# Help with understanding a summation formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I am having trouble understanding the derivation of the summation formula below.

> [$$\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac1{(k+1)(k+2)} = \dfrac{N}{2N+4}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%281%2F%28%28k%2B1%29%28k%2B2%29%29%29+from+k+%3D+1+to+N)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that $$\dfrac1{(k+1)(k+2)} = \dfrac1{k+1} - \dfrac1{k+2}$$ and do a telescopic cancellation.

Move your mouse over the gray area for the complete solution.

> Hence, we have \begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac1{(k+1)(k+2)} & = \sum_{k=1}^N \left(\dfrac1{k+1} - \dfrac1{k+2} \right)\\ & = \left(\dfrac12 - \dfrac13 \right) + \left(\dfrac13 - \dfrac14 \right) + \cdots + \left(\dfrac1N - \dfrac1{N+1} \right) + \left(\dfrac1{N+1} - \dfrac1{N+2} \right)\\ & = \dfrac12 - \left(\dfrac13 - \dfrac13 \right) - \left(\dfrac14 - \dfrac14 \right) - \cdots - \left(\dfrac1{N+1} - \dfrac1{N+1} \right) - \dfrac1{N+2}\\ & = \dfrac12 - \dfrac1{N+2}\\ & = \dfrac{N+2-2}{2(N+2)}\\ & = \dfrac{N}{2N+4} \end{align}

Comment: thank you , it was confusing at first , but you pointed me in the right path.